# Remove recommended packages

Tags: package-management

By mistake I forgot to add `--no-install-recommends` flag to my `apt-get` install command, is there a way to purge those recommended packages after they've been installed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to enzotibs answer, if you wish to avoid adding `--no-install-recommends` each time, you can also disable automatic installation of recommended package by setting the `APT::Install-Recommends` setting to `0`:

```
umask 0022;echo 'APT::Install-Recommends "0";' | \
    sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00DisableInstallRecommends
```

The `umask 0022` causes the file to be created with permissions 644, restrictive permissions breaks operations like `apt-get -s ...` (simulate).

Answer (score 3):

I think the sequence

```
sudo apt-get purge $packages
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install $packages
```

is the way to go.

Comment: No reason to purge first.
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends reinstall $packages && sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: Barafu, that's the way to go, I think. Post an answer so I may accept.

Comment: @Barafu Albino: apart from the fact that `reinstall` is wrong, maybe you mean `--reinstall install`, but even when corrected, it don't seem to work, from my tests.

Comment: Ok, I should add that my test are on 10.10, cannot test at the moment on 11.04.