# How do I undo and install the proprietary GPU driver?

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, gpu

At https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

I did steps 1 to 3. However, instead of doing step 4, I did: `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends bumblebee linux-headers-generic`?

If one day, I wanted to install the proprietary drivers instead. How would I undo this? Will running `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic` do it, or would I need to do other things first?

Answer (score 1):

`--no-install-recommends` prevent certain packages from being installed, mainly the nvidia driver. If you have bumblebee already installed, it is sufficient to run:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic
```

Comment: And what if it was the other way around? i.e. I installed bumblebee-nvidia first via `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic` and wanted to revert. Is it enough to run: `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends bumblebee linux-headers-generic`?

Comment: @ChristianFazzini I don't know a method which I tested, but maybe http://askubuntu.com/q/39579/6969 is of help for you?