# How to completely remove ubuntu-restricted-extras

Tags: ubuntu-restricted-extras

I recently installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras` but it is causing bugs in Google Chrome, and I want want to remove it. However, when I do it using `sudo apt-get autoremove` or `sudo apt-get purge` it doesn't seem to be completely removed because when I was installing it, a lot of packages got removed and others got installed.
My question is: How do I make things just like they was before installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`?
Thanks.

Comment: That package should not cause "bugs" in Google Chrome. Quite a few of us have the restricted extras installed and Google Chrome works perfectly. Perhaps you'd like to explain what exactly are the bugs? Maybe there's another cause for them?

Comment: I think that restricted extras is causing the bug because Chrome was working fine before installing it. But now, when I try to publish something on Twitter, start from the beginning even though I put it at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use synaptic.  If you don't have it installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Once done, open synaptic, by typing it in dash, and once it opens search for `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, right click, and choose Mark for Complete Removal, and then click on Apply.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But is this going to reinstall the packages that were removed during the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installation?

Comment: No.  Packages removed probably are not needed anymore.  Any package in particular you're concerned about?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that the ubuntu-restricted-* metapackages use recommendations instead of dependencies. If you want to completely remove the packages recommended by either of these, a safe way is to do it manually (tested on Ubuntu 14.04.3):

- `apt-cache show ubuntu-restricted-extras`
- `apt-cache show ubuntu-restricted-addons`
- Take note of all the "Recommends:" packages.
- `apt-get remove ubuntu-restricted-extras ubuntu-restricted-addons`
- `apt-get remove` for all the recommended packages
- `apt-get autoremove` to get rid of the installed dependencies for the recommended packages.

Then if you want you can do a clean reinstall:

- `apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` to get everything back

Note that `apt-get install --reinstall` for all of the recommended packages would not be thorough enough as it would not get rid of the installed dependencies for the recommended packages.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is irrespective of the problem you faced with Google Chrome. 
It's an answer to the title's question.

The ubuntu-restricted-extras package, is a dummy package that installs other packages and libraries as well.

Here is an example list

```
cabextract flashplugin-installer freepats gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly liba52-0.7.4 libass4 libavcodec-extra-53 libavformat53 libavutil-extra-51
  libcdaudio1 libdc1394-22 libdca0 libdirac-encoder0 libdirectfb-1.2-9 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libenca0 libfaac0 libfaad2 libfftw3-3 libfftw3-double3 libflite1 libgme0 libgsm1
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libkate1 libmad0 libmimic0 libmjpegutils-2.0-0 libmms0 libmodplug1 libmp3lame0 libmpcdec6 libmpeg2-4
  libmpeg2encpp-2.0-0 libmpg123-0 libmplex2-2.0-0 libnspr4-0d libnss3-1d libofa0 liboil0.3 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopencore-amrnb0 libopencore-amrwb0 libopenjpeg2 libopus0
  libpostproc52 libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsidplay1 libslv2-9 libsoundtouch0 libspandsp2 libswscale2 libts-0.0-0 libtwolame0 libva1 libvo-aacenc0 libvo-amrwbenc0
  libwildmidi-config libwildmidi1 libx264-123 libxvidcore4 libzbar0 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 tsconf ttf-mscorefonts-installer ubuntu-restricted-addons ubuntu-restricted-extras
  unrar
```

You can copy-paste the above code to a txt file and run

```
sudo apt-get remove $(cat somefile.txt)
```

Be Aware that the package-libraries versions may vary. Above is from Ubuntu 13.10.

Also you can locate the command you gave "apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras" in apt history log files and see which packages this command had installed.

Try

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log
```

If the installation is recent it will be listed there, if is older, you can try other history logs as well. e.g. history.log.1.gz (you can list .gz files with `zcat` instead of cat)

Answer (score 0):

@Mitch answer doesn't remove completely ubuntu-restricted-extras package (at least in Ubuntu 14.04). Certainly because ubuntu-restricted-extras has not much "depends" packages but "recommends" instead, that are installed automatically by default.

```
apt-cache depends ubuntu-restricted-extras
  Depends: ubuntu-restricted-addons
  Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer
  Recommends: unrar
  Recommends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse
  Recommends: <libavcodec-extra-53>
  Conflicts: ubuntu-restricted-extras:i386

apt-cache depends ubuntu-restricted-addons
ubuntu-restricted-addons
  Recommends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
  Recommends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
  Recommends: flashplugin-installer
    flashplugin-installer:i386
  Recommends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
  Recommends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
  Recommends: gstreamer1.0-libav
  Recommends: gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3
  Recommends: gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3
  Recommends: chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
  Recommends: oxideqt-codecs-extra
  Conflicts: ubuntu-restricted-addons:i386
```

Unfortunately apt-get purge package and apt-get autoremove --purge don't remove "recommends" packages ([Remove recommended packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39579/remove-recommended-packages)) even after you uninstall ubuntu-restricted-extras and ubuntu-restricted-addons, so you have to uninstall manually what you don't need (I had ttf-mscorefonts-installer, unrar and flashplugin-installer already installed):

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-restricted-extras ubuntu-restricted-addons gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse libavcodec-extra-53 gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3 oxideqt-codecs-extra
```

On my computer, removing chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra wants to uninstall chromium, so I had to install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg and it will uninstall chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg
```