# MPV 0.35.0 on Ubuntu 22.10 - Not working correctly

Tags: 22.10, mpv-media-player

There is a new version of MPV available for Ubuntu 22.10, if one uses the default `sudo apt-get install mpv` you get version 0.34.1, so to get 0.35.0 you apparently have to compile it with `waf` and install it... which I eventually managed to do, via the following method of sorts.
[image]

Using the `waf` method shown in the `README.md` file I had to install a bunch of extra packages just to get `./waf configure` to run through so I could compile it, albeit with a flag of `--disable-gl`

The packages I had to install were: GCC, cmake, pkg-config, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-dev, libass-dev, libavcodec-dev, libavfilter-dev, libavfilter-extra8, libavutil-dev

Then I did ./waf followed by a final install step I had to do with root via sudo su for ./waf install

Unfortunately, I am still trying to get it to run right because it keeps sending me to Ubuntu software to install codecs to run my files. Upon installing `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras` in a **misguided** attempt to get all codecs I have broken my PC in that clicking on any media file now logs me out. :(

I found a partial fix with this problem I have and can now open media files again.I tried `sudo apt-get --purge remove ubuntu-restricted-extras` the codecs... but had to install Synaptic to completely remove it.

I got the system partially fixed, but MPV still doesn't play video's very well, any suggestions appreciated to get it working right. opengl doesn't seem to be working and I don't have an option for va-api

Comment: Yup, sometimes that happens when testing bleeding-edge software. A lot of testing and sometimes a bit of fixing goes into deb packages. Thanks for being a tester, and be sure to file proper bug reports so those problems can be reproduced, triaged, and fixed.

Comment: Looks like a found a partial answer at: https://askubuntu.com/a/326047/1554660 and thus by installing synaptic I was able to remove ubuntu-restricted-extras properly and fix the system back to the point it's not logging me out when I click on a media file anymore.  Video is now playing back in MPV now as well but its super chunky, so yeah its a work in progress